# sbt assembly command not found

Tags: sbt, sbt-assembly

I'm trying to run sbt assembly. According to https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly  , for sbt 0.13.6+ (I'm on 0.13.7) this should be included automatically for anything with the JvmPlugin. According to `sbt plugins` I have the JvmPlugin enabled in root. When I run `sbt assembly` I get "Not a valid commamdn: assembly". I've tried using old methods of including sbt-assembly with all the different types of sbt configurations, but none seem to work. Here's what my build files look like (note sbt package works fine)

assembly.sbt

`addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si8n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.13.0")`

build.sbt

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  organization := "com.test",
  version := "1.0",
  scalaVersion := "2.10.4"
)

lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    name := "test",

    resolvers ++= Seq(
      ...
    ),

    libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
      ...
    )
)
```

Here is the error:

```
[error] Not a valid command: assembly
[error] Not a valid project ID: assembly
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: assembly
[error] assembly
[error]
```

Any ideas? Running on Linux. Thanks

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Did you create a `assembly.sbt` at the root of your project? Alongside your `build.sbt`?

If so, then that's the problem. You want to have it inside the `project` directory.

Having done that it worked out the box as expected with the rest of your setup:

```
> assembly
[info] Including: scala-library.jar
[info] Checking every *.class/*.jar file's SHA-1.
[info] Merging files...
[warn] Merging 'META-INF/MANIFEST.MF' with strategy 'discard'
[warn] Strategy 'discard' was applied to a file
[info] SHA-1: 1ae0d7a9c433e439e81ce947659bf05aa62a2892
[info] Packaging /Users/dnw/Desktop/t-2015-04-08.2340/target/scala-2.10/test-assembly-1.0.jar ...
[info] Done packaging.
[success] Total time: 2 s, completed 08-Apr-2015 23:45:59
```

Comment: In my case, the `sbt.version` in the `build.properties` file in the `project` directory wasn't set to `0.13.16` . After setting it properly, the error went away.

Answer (score 2):

Since the introduction of auto plugins in 0.13.5, adding explicit .sbt files for plugins (except for specific cases where the plugin does not implement auto-plugin trait) is not recommended per [sbt documentation](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Using-Plugins.html).

Add the `addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si8n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.13.0")` back to `plugins.sbt` under `project` directory and remove `assembly.sbt`.  if you still see the error, explicitly enable the plugin in the build.sbt:

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    name := "test",
  ).
  enablePlugins(AssemblyPlugin)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
lazy val root = (project in file(".")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    assemblySettings ++ Seq(
    jarName in assembly := "roobricks-spark.jar",
    test in assembly := {}
  ).
  enablePlugins(AssemblyPlugin)
```

can you once with this.

Answer (score 2):

Same thing happened to me. Move `assembly.sbt` from the root to inside your `project/` directory

Answer (score 1):

Came across the same error. The reason was I executing it from the wrong inside target folder

Comment: I got your same error as Jonathan, and when I cd into the stixloader folder, and ran the command, it worked better.  However I still got an error:
`download failed: org.slf4j#slf4j-api;1.7.25!slf4j-api.jar`.  


The solution I found on the web was to just run the command once more.  It then was able to download slf4j and it then proceeded create the stixloader-1.1.jar.

Answer (score 1):

You should normally have a `plugins.sbt` file at the root level alongside your `build.properties` where you should have the following:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.15.0")
```

Answer (score 0):

From sparkour:

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.14.4") with assembly.plugin does work