# SBT Assembly not working (not a valid command)

Tags: scala, jar, sbt, sbt-assembly

I have tried a lot of solutions that I could find related to this topic. Above all of them,

[sbt assembly command not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29523694/sbt-assembly-command-not-found][1])

looked the most related, but that did not solve it.

I am using sbt 13.7

build.sbt:

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  organization := "com.example",
  version := "0.1.0"
)

lazy val app = (project in file(".")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    name := "fat-jar-test"
  )
```

assembly.sbt:

```
resolvers += Resolver.url("bintray-sbt-plugins", url("http://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases"))(Resolver.ivyStylePatterns)

addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.11.2")
```

project structure

```
root
  |
  src
  target
  project
    |
    build.sbt
    assembly.sbt
```

In sbt I compile succesfully, I can package succesfully, but when I run assembly command I get:

```
[error] Not a valid command: assembly
[error] Not a valid project ID: assembly
[error] Expected ':' (if selecting a configuration)
[error] Not a valid key: assembly
[error] assembly
[error]
```

I am using Intellij but running sbt from terminal.
I am on Mac OSX.
I originally downloaded sbt and installed from their site, normal installation. I removed and tried installing from macports, no difference.
I had scala version in build.sbt setting, but removed it because I was getting errors and read the 2.11.x does not work with sbt. That stopped errors, but I still have assembly problem.

EDIT:

I was unsure of placement of build.sbt in this structure. Before I had it in the root directory. At suggest of Roman below, I have moved it back to there, but alas I receive the exact same error.

Comment: What `plugins` command shows?

Comment: sbt.plugins.IvyPlugin: enabled in app  
sbt.plugins.JvmPlugin: enabled in app  
sbt.plugins.CorePlugin: enabled in app  
sbt.plugins.JUnitXmlReportPlugin: enabled in app

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Pull 1 level up your `build.sbt`. It should reside in project root, not it `project`.

Also it's possible to have `build.sbt` in `project` folder as well, it means a different thing. Read [Organizing Build](http://www.scala-sbt.org/0.13/docs/Organizing-Build.html) document for some insight.

UPD: as @marios has suggested, can you also put resolvers to your build.sbt. Also, it's important to set SNAPSHOT version for your build. The whole content of your `build.sbt` should be the following:

```
scalaVersion in ThisBuild := "2.11.7"

lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  organization := "com.example",
  version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT"
)

lazy val app = (project in file(".")).
  settings(commonSettings: _*).
  settings(
    name := "fat-jar-test"
  ).
  enablePlugins(AssemblyPlugin)

resolvers in Global ++= Seq(
  "Sbt plugins"                   at "https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases",
  "Maven Central Server"          at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2",
  "TypeSafe Repository Releases"  at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
  "TypeSafe Repository Snapshots" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/snapshots/"
)
```

Then, add two more files to `root/project` folder:

`root/project/build.properties` contains a single line:

```
sbt.version=0.13.7
```

`root/project/plugins.sbt` also contains a single line:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n"       %  "sbt-assembly"            % "0.12.0")
```

Now, remove your `root/project/assembly.sbt` file (although it's fine to have it instead of `plugins.sbt`, but let's just try - this configuration always works for me).

Now, your project layout should be the following:

```
root
  |
  build.sbt
  src
  project
    |
    plugins.sbt
    build.properties
```

Reload sbt and try `plugins` command. You should see `sbtassembly.AssemblyPlugin` there.

Comment: I had tried this, and just changed it back to this. Exact same error. I will edit question to reflect this.

Comment: This answer is very close to correct so I don't want to add a new address. Your build.sbt files needs to be inside your root directory. Also the resolvers statements should be inside your build.sbt and not inside the plugin sbt file.

Comment: @marios I had tried that also, and at your suggestion I put it back in build.sbt. So far no possible combination has worked and I get same error. Roman asked for plugins output in comments under main question. From that it looks like the plugin is not listed.

Comment: You need to add `enablePlugins(AssemblyPlugin)`

Comment: This was helpful. For me, the missing item was the root/project/plugins.sbt file. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @DexterLegaspi where do I need to add ```enablePlugins(AssemblyPlugin)```?
At plugins.sbt?

Comment: I had tried this but I got this error `error: not found: value AssemblyPlugin
enablePlugins(AssemblyPlugin)`
can you help me please ?

Comment: getting the same error as above ^ has anyone solved this?

Answer (score 5):

The same problem occurred for me.
i had the correct structure of files and folder.

The mistake i was doing is running the sbt assembly from the myproject/project folder.
Try running same command from top project folder.
run from C:\Users**\IdeaProjects\untitled9
not from C:\Users**\IdeaProjects\untitled9\project

Comment: this one worked for me