# Why does sbt assembly fail with "Not a valid command: assembly"?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, sbt, sbt-assembly

I installed Spark to `C:\Spark1_6\spark-1.6.0-bin-hadoop2.6`. After navigating to this path I am entering `sbt assembly` command and I am getting the following error message:

```
[error] Not a valid command: assembly
[error] Not a valid project ID: assembly
[error] Expected ':'
[error] Not a valid key: assembly
[error] assembly
[error]         ^
```

Here is my sbt project structure.

```
-Project101
  -project
     -build.properties
     -plugins.sbt
-src
-build.sbt
```

Here is my `build.sbt`:

```
name := "Project101"
version := "1.0"
scalaVersion := "2.10.2"
libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-core_2.10" % "1.6.0" exclude ("org.apache.hadoop","hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy"),
  "org.apache.spark" % "spark-sql_2.10" % "1.6.0" exclude ("org.apache.hadoop","hadoop-yarn-server-web-proxy"),
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-hive" % "1.6.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming" % "1.6.0",
  "org.apache.spark" %% "spark-streaming-kafka" % "1.6.0"
)
resolvers in Global ++= Seq(
  "Sbt plugins"                   at "https://dl.bintray.com/sbt/sbt-plugin-releases",
  "Maven Central Server"          at "http://repo1.maven.org/maven2",
  "TypeSafe Repository Releases"  at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
  "TypeSafe Repository Snapshots" at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/snapshots/"
)
```

Here is the `plugins.sbt`:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.12.0")
```

`sbt package` command is working and able to create the jar file. But I had to execute `sbt assembly` command too but is not working.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/a/29526644/4355342

Answer (score 7):

> Not a valid command: assembly

Whenever you face the error message, please make sure you're in the top-level directory of the project with the [sbt-assembly](https://github.com/sbt/sbt-assembly) plugin installed.

If you have a project in `Project101` directory, make sure that `project/plugins.sbt` has the line in:

```
addSbtPlugin("com.eed3si9n" % "sbt-assembly" % "0.12.0")
```

With that, you should again be in `Project101` directory and execute `sbt assembly`. That should execute the plugin to create an uber-jar.

Answer (score 1):

As correctly stated in another answer, the issue is caused by running `sbt assembly` not from the project directory.

If you getting that issue within Docker container, make sure that your mounts are set correctly.

For example:

```
docker run ... -v $$PWD/:/<your Scala project directory here> -w /<your Scala project directory here> <your build image> bash -c "sbt assembly"
```